# How to return a value using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, callable, countdownlatch, completable-future

I created an example, i want to know how can I return a value using the `CompletableFuture` ? I also changed the `CompletableFuture<Void> exeFutureList` to be `CompletableFuture<Integer> exeFutureList` but eclipse always suggest to 
set it back to Void.

Please let me know how to return value using CompletableFuture.

**Code**:

```
    public class MainClass {

    static ExecutorService exe = null;
    static CompletableFuture<Void> exeFutureList = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        exeFutureList = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new RunClass(8), exe);
    }

    static class RunClass implements Runnable {

        private int num;

        public RunClass(int num) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.num = num;
        }

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.num = this.num + 10;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Runnable` is just an interface with a `run` method that does not return anything.

Therefore the [`runAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) method that you are using returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`

You need to submit a `Supplier`, using the [`supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) method:

```
final int arg = 8;
CompletableFuture<Integer> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return arg + 10;
}, exe);
```

You can also create your own `Supplier<Integer>` implementation instead of using lambda.